# Couldn't get data and insert data for Angularjs , PHP MySQL

Tags: php, angularjs

There are two tables and I can get data from one table(customers) . However I couldn't get data from second table with this code .

in short, Our system get all of data from send.html and insert to database with below code in one table . I would like to get id data from Login table after that I will insert this id and other customers data .

```
$app->post('/send', function() use ($app) {
    $response = array();
    $qwr = json_decode($app->request->getBody());
    verifyRequiredParams(array('email', 'name', 'password'),$r->customer);
    require_once 'passwordHash.php';
    $db = new DbHandler();
    $phone = $qwr->customer->phone;
    $name = $qwr->customer->name;
    $email = $qwr->customer->email;
    $address = $qwr->customer->address;
    $password = $qwr->customer->password;
    $isUserExists = $db->getOneRecord("select * from **login** where phone='$phone' or email='$email'");
    if(!$isUserExists){
        $qwr->customer->password = passwordHash::hash($password);
        $tabble_name = "**customers**";
        $column_names = array('uid', 'phone', 'name', 'email', 'password', 'city', 'address', 'rname', 'rmail', 'rbcode', 'tfor', 'cnumber', 'cname', 'edate', 'cwc', 'badress', 'hname', 'sstreet', 'scity', 'scountry', 'scode', 'toValue', 'amount');
        $result = $db->insertIntoTable($r->customer, $column_names, $tabble_name);
        if ($result != NULL) {
            $response["status"] = "success";
            $response["message"] = "successfully";
            $response["uid"] = $result;
            if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
                session_start();
            }
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $response["uid"];
            $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['rname'] = $rname;
            echoResponse(200, $response);
```

Whats your advice ?